# Is it possible to remove the ability to choose between which sim card to send text from default android sms application?

Tags: samsung, sms, stock-android, customization, android-10

I have this requirement where I need to completely disable sending sms and calls even by accident from SIM 2 which I only use for Mobile data (Sometimes I Force network to LTE and SMS and calls won't be made even by accident when its locked to LTE my issue is when not network is in auto mode). One suggestion to prevent accidental messages is to keep the balance 0. But sometimes I get free messages bundled with packages ;)

[image]

The red arrow shows the option for SIM 2 messaging option. Is there anyway to remove that option? (much better without root)

My device is Samsung A30 & android version is 10, Using android messages version 11.1.60.153.

Comment: *settings - SIM card*